# Dividing remaining width by two divs and hiding a div upon relative push

Tags: html, css

(not a duplicate, I've read the other answers).

**HTML**

```
<div id="ultra_div">
    <div id="other_div">HOVER ME</div>
    <div id="btw_which_ones_pink">It is okay for the pink div to be pushed, it's actually as planned</div>
    <div id="to_divide">
        <div id="part_one">this will, inevitably, vary</div>
        <div id="part_two">this width won't vary</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#ultra_div{
    width: 300px;
}

#btw_which_ones_pink{
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}
#other_div:hover{
    width: 320px;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out; 
    -webkit-transition:width 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition:width 0.5s ease-out;
    transition:width 0.5s ease-out;
}

#other_div{
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
     background-color: black;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}

#to_divide{
    width: 100%;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:box;
    height: 150px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index: 9;
}

#part_two{
    background-color: yellow;
    right: 0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 93%;
    margin: 4px;
}
#part_one{
    background-color:white;
    width:72%;
    margin: 4px;
    height: 93%;
}
```

Hello there, what I want is described here and in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Exa2K/4/)! :)

1-> It is okay for the pink div to be pushed, it's actually as planned

2-> ... but **I don't want the blue div to be pushed down**. I want the pink div to hide behind the blue div while it (the blue div) remains at the same "top" attribute.

The position of all divs ought to be "relative" because the height of the black and pink divs may vary and the height of the blue div depends on them. So, with "relative" I can assure the blue div is inserted right underneath the square divs because of its width 100%;

I had accomplished all this before but when I tried to do my main objective it all just didn't fit, so I erased the code and tried again.

3-> I want the blue div to be divided in width by two divs, the yellow part_two and white part_one. The second part (yellow) is fixed. The width of it won't vary. The problem is that the width of the blue div may vary. This means that the width of the white div I want to achieve is actually the width of the blue div - the width of the yellow div. Unfortunately, until now this has been a really pain in the buttocks so I thought I would try and find some help here. **Pure CSS**

Please, only submit an answer if you accomplish 1,2 and 3.

Comment: If you have multiple questions you should ask them separately. Your points 1 & 2 make up a single question while your point 3 is a separate question altogether.

Comment: @Nit thing is, they must all work together nonetheless. I've tried that before and people always end up changing the code and it won't work as I need it to.

Comment: When you mouse over the "hover" black div, you want the pink div to appear in front of the blue div?

Comment: @MarcAudet *"I want the pink div to hide behind the blue div while it (the blue div) remains at the same "top" attribute."* . Behind, that is...

Answer (score 0):

Use this css rule:

```
#other_div:hover+#btw_which_ones_pink~#to_divide{
  //your code
}
```

to select "to_divide" div.

Then, apply what you need.

`display: box` does not exist, right one is `flex`

You'll need to change some position and display while in `hover` state (those rules need rest of the page to be effective so I'll don't lose time tryin' to fit your request), however, why don't simply make btw_which_ones_pink display:none ?

```
    #other_div:hover+#btw_which_ones_pink{
  display: none;
}
```